# Encoding Request Body

Tags: angular, request

I have a requirement that I encode the body of all outgoing requests (including standard json) in my Angular application.  I'm using HttpClient to make requests, but as far as I can tell I don't have access to the serialization layer in Angular.  (It looks like this happens in HttpRequest.serializeBody, which is not something I can or should modify)

Is there a good way to encode outgoing request bodies in an Angular application?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a HttpService that extends the default HttpClient and then set the headers for encoding type. If you additionally extend the HttpRequest and override the `serializeBody`

Comment: I encode json to prevent certain characters and I'm not sure setting the headers will affect the json object encoding.  Once I extend HttpRequest how would I use it?